# invalid argument value and bad dump file specification when I try to impdp in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, impdp

I'm trying get the SQL DDL statements from a Data Pump dmp file. However I'm getting this when I run impdp:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-31619: invalid dump file "D:\Oracle\dmp\mydmp.dmp"
```

I'm trying to run this command:

```
impdp myuser/password directory=mydir dumpfile=mydmp.dmp sqlfile=myddl.sql logfile=mylog.log;
```

My user got pretty much all privileges and read, write access to the directory.

I'm doing this to retrieve the tablespaces from this dmp file.
My end goal is to fully restore this database that was done from another machine. I was told that before importing this DB to a new machine that I need to get the tablespaces and re-create the same ones on the new machine. The old machine also had a different user.

Sorry if all this sounds basic. It's my first time playing with Oracle DB.

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Are you sure the dump file was created with data pump `expdp` export tool, not with the legacy `exp` export tool?

Comment: I have no idea. I will ask the person who did the export. What if it was done using legacy exp export tool ?

Comment: Then you can use legacy `imp` instead of `impdp`. I'm not sure if that is the issue here though, I would have thought you'd also get ORA-39143. Maybe the file has been corrupted, e.g. by ftp'ing as ascii instead of binary, but guessing really. Can you also check (if it was `expdp`) which version the source DB was, and that is the the same as the one you're trying to import into, or that yours is a higher version?

Comment: Right... if you (or the person doing the export) has access to My Oracle Support, look at Doc ID 549750.1. Sounds like a version mismatch is probably the issue here.

Comment: The export was done with Oracle11g Release 1 using this command    
 `exp '/ as sysdba' full=Y rows=y file='%MYDIR%\exp_%2.full_%1.dmp' log='%MYDIR%\exp_%2.full_%1.txt' buffer=65536 grants=y indexes=y compress=y consistent=y constraints=Y statistics=NONE`

Comment: Please, use the following (replacing `myuser/password@sid` with your database credentials) to import with IMP utility:     `imp 'myuser/password@sid as sysdba' file=D:\Oracle\dmp\mydmp.dmp log=D:\Oracle\dmp\imp_mydmp.log full=y grants=y indexes=y rows=y constraints=y`

Comment: Did you succeeded in the end ? If so, how ? :)